# InvalidParameterException when trying to reset password cognito

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am trying to rest the password of the cognito user, I used following code for that function

```
async resetPassword(event: ResetPassword) {
    try {
      const { email, newPassword, session } = event;
      const input = {
        ClientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        ChallengeName: ChallengeNameType.NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED,
        ChallengeResponses: { USERNAME: email, NEW_PASSWORD: newPassword },
        Session: session,
      };
      const command = new RespondToAuthChallengeCommand(input);

      const response = await this.cognitoClient.send(command);
      return sendResponse(StatusCodes.OK, {
        status: ResponseStatus.SUCCESS,
        message: SuccessMessages.USER_LOGGED_IN,
        data: response,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

Then I used Postman to call the API. When using that I am getting the following error.

> "body": { "name": "InvalidParameterException", "$fault": "client",
> "$metadata": { "httpStatusCode": 400, "requestId":
> "66a714b4-7a05-4eb5-ae3e-cfeac186fdaa", "attempts": 1,
> "totalRetryDelay": 0 }, "__type": "InvalidParameterException" }

[image]

What could go wrong here?

Comment: I think `UserPoolId` is not an expected parameter, can you try without it?

Comment: I don't know how you have initialized `ChallengeName` but you can try setting it as `ChallengeName: "NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED"`.

Comment: @ArpitJain I got ChallengeName from `import {ChallengeNameType,} from "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider";`

I tried your way too, but no luck . Removing poolID is not a fix

Comment: You got same error message?

Comment: @ArpitJain yes do

Comment: I don't see the `UserPoolId` as a valid parameter here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/interfaces/respondtoauthchallengecommandinput.html

Comment: Can you confirm if all the parameter have values?

Comment: @ArpitJain, I logged err.message. Now showing     "message": "Invalid attributes given, name is missing",

Comment: I think you also need to pass name `'userAttributes.name': '<>'` inside `ChallengeResponses`